# TweetView cause ANR when first appear on screen

Tags: android, twitter, view, tweets

I use 3.0.0 version of [Android Twitter SDK](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview), init with:

```
        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET))
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.INFO))
                .debug(false)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
```

and simple create with:

```
    CompactTweetView tweetView = new CompactTweetView(activity, getTweetJsonData());
    tweetView.setTweetActionsEnabled(true);
```

in **RecyclerView**, and after i going to this screen with [CompactTweetView](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/javadocs/tweet-ui/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/CompactTweetView.html) i got ANR problem around 15-20 secs. Only for first time in app instance, secondary and other items shows instantly. If i close and open screen again items also show instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was been in sdk-init:

```
Twitter.initialize(config);
```

That i call in NOT ui-thread (i call it in AsyncTask), after i change to Application.onCreate() method, problem has been solved